# C++ string reference cannot co-exist

Tags: c++

A newbie question, could someone please help to understand the error message below? If use `void getPath(string cur, ...)` without reference, and it will work. Or we can use `for (auto s : parents[cur]) {...}` without reference, it will also work.

Why both reference cannot coexist? The error message is mysterious to me and it is easy to make the same mistake again and again.

The main function will call `getPath(endWord, beginWord, parents, path, res);`

Error message is `error: binding reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'} to 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' discards qualifiers`.

The function is shown below

```
//function tries to obtain all paths to beginWord, starting from endWord
void getPath(
    string& cur,
    string& beginWord, 
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>& parents, 
    vector<string>& path, 
    vector<vector<string>>& res) 
{ 
    if (cur == beginWord) {
        path.push_back(cur);
        reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
        res.push_back(path);

        reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
        path.pop_back();
        return;
    }

    path.push_back(cur);
    for (auto& s : parents[cur]) {
        getPath(s, beginWord, parents, path, res); //Here it cause error message.
    }
    path.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: Elements of `unordered_set` are `const`. You can't bind a non-`const` reference to a `const` object.

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat,  could you please provide some link? I did not found the const for value_type here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/

Comment: It says that `iterator` is *"a forward iterator to `const value_type`"*.

Comment: Or instead of cplusplus.com, cppreference.com says that with regard to a [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), "*Container elements may not be modified (even by non const iterators) since modification could change an element's hash and corrupt the container.*" The same concept also applies to std::set because modification could similarly corrupt the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AAC. It means Almost Always Const.

I have invented this acronym just now. I hoped it exists and is widely used, but to my astonishment, it is not. So let's start now!

```
void getPath(
    const string& cur,
    const string& beginWord, 
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>& parents, 
    vector<string>& path, 
    vector<vector<string>>& res)
```

There are more ways to improve this piece of code.

---

`parents` is not made `const` because there is a `[]` operator applied to it inside, and it requires a non-const. Can you make do with `find` instead? If so, `parents` should also be `const`.

---

`res` probably should not be a parameter, but rather a return value. Don't worry about efficiency, it will work fine thanks to RVO.

---

Reversing `path` every time looks wasteful, why not keep it reversed to begin with? You will need `push_front` instead of `push_back`, which means it probably wants to be a deque rather than a vector.

---

`unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>` is probably better off being `unordered_multimap<string, string>`.

---

Finally, `path` can also be made a `const` reference. This requires making copies of it inside. This may or may not be a small price to pay for keeping the interface pure.

Comment: Hmph. Nearly always, passing a string as a `std::string_view` is preferable to passing it as a `std::string const&`. The rare exceptions are when the callee needs a null terminated string. And a `std::span<const T>` is preferable to a `std::vector<T> const&`. The added flexibility and efficiency is always good.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't see compelling reasons for using string_view here. The arguments are strings, the result is a bunch of strings, it doesn't make much sense to switch back and forth between the two all the time.